# Laravel attach a callable to onDelete to eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model that needs to delete images when the model is deleted. The model I will be calling is `Seminar.php`. This "Seminar" model has got instructors in the model called `SeminarInstructor.php`. Suppose I called `Seminar::find(1)->delete();` to delete the seminar with `id = 1`-- I would also need this delete off any instructors connected to the model as below:

```
public function seminarInstructor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SeminarInstructor::class, 'seminar_id', 'id');
    }
```

I have enabled cascading, so when I call delete, laravel/mysql should automatically resolve it. However, I have a method called `public function deleteCloudImage1()` in `SeminarInstructor.php` which handles the deletion logic for the image existing in my table as a url. I could manually call this method before I delete a `seminar` model, but I want to know if there is any convenient method to handle this in eloquent/laravel. I looked up the code a bit and there seems to be a callable attribute called `onDelete` in the implementation. Anyone know how to use this, or any other alternative.

Comment: You can use the deleting event on your model https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events

Comment: I feel like that attaching the image deletion logic to `deleting` will cause a race condition because I will need to get the image url link from db before its deleted.

Comment: @SilverFlash set image url to variable before delete-query run and delete file after delete-query success

Comment: The cascading deletion of the instructor is implemented in the application in laravel or at the database level mysql? Because from this then arise the possibilities of how to solve this issue correctly and effectively.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, I think using a closure in your Seminar model will suffice. Something like `protected static function booted() { static::deleting(function ($model) { $model->seminarInstructor->deleteCloudImage1(); }); }`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ where and how does `booted()` get called?
@MartinOsusky It's set at db level, I have enabled cascading on migration.
@RapSherlock Preferably I would want less overhead as well

Comment: When you instantiate the model, eg `Seminar::find(1);`, and the deleting when you call `->delete();` on a instance. Note that `deleting` is called before the model has been deleted, so you will still have access to its data and relationships

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ That is actually nice. I need to test that out.